# RPi emulating a keyboard, how to send certain keycodes(left-meta)?

Tags: python, keyboard, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm working on emulating a keyboard with an rpi, but for some reason writing `b'\xe3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0'` to hidg0 is pressing the left shift, ctrl, alt and meta keys when it should theoretically just press the left meta key.

I'm getting this information from the https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hut1_12v2.pdf on page 59 where it shows that the keycode for left meta is 227, which in hex is xe3